# Alternatives for getLastKnownLocation

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using Google maps v2 and sometimes getLastKnownLocation() returns NULL. is there an alternative to have the same effect but with a higher stability? Thanks for helping

Comment: What is it you need their location for? getLastKnownLocation() can sometimes return very out of date information, if its not null. Also if you could provide what you've done so far it would help us answer

Comment: How much do you ask for a position?
If you need to ask for getLastKnowLocation frecuently (as example one time each five minutes). I think you need to suscribe to a location provider.

Comment: I just want the location right now, and I just need it once. No need to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, getLastKnownLocation() should only return null if the user has turned off location for your app (Marshmallow) or turned off location for all apps (Lollipop and below). Also, be sure to call locationManager.requestSingleUpdate() before calling getLastKnownLocation.

This is some pretty reliable code, (if I don't get a location within 5 attempts I assume we can't get the location):

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && locMan != null) {

            String provider;

            provider = locMan.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getName();

            if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
                Looper.prepare();
            }

            int count = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                locMan.requestSingleUpdate(provider, null, Looper.myLooper());
                location = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                if (location != null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

An alternative, you can apply for location updates using locationManager.requestLocationUpdates() and give it a LocationListener. The listener will fire when the OS gets a location update.

Comment: Me too - awesome solution!

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. Since you already have a `locationListener` object that you give as a parameter for `requestSingleUpdate()`, you should wait for the asynchronous call to finish and the listener's `onLocationChanged()` to be triggered. Then the `getLastKnownLocation()` is unnecessary. As finding the location takes a while, it's not available right away and the first call returns `null`.  Now this works because of the delay and retry (polling) mechanism. And if this is ran on the main thread, this blocks the main thread. It may be "pretty reliable", but it's an ugly hack. :)

Comment: Admittedly, I should have mentioned that I run the above code in a thread, I was merely trying to answer Steven's question.